# How to test a class async method in jest and Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am using spies to test async methods from a class. In the User model I created a async static method that checking an array of objects of the type User and returns the User if is found.

```
  static comparePasswordHash = async (hash: string, plainPassword: string) => await bcrypt.compare(plainPassword, hash);

  static getUser = async (email: string, passwordPlain: string): Promise<User | Error> => {
    try {
        const userData: any = await readSmallRecord(FileNames.Users);
        const users: User[] = JSON.parse(userData);

        const user = users.find(user => user.email === email.toLowerCase());

        if (!user) return new Error('User not found');

        const matchPassword = await this.comparePasswordHash(user.password, passwordPlain);
        if (!matchPassword) return new Error('Invalid credentials');
        return user;

    } 
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return new Error('Failed to fetch user data');
    }
  };
```

In the testing file, I mock the module, set the spies to spy on the `getUser` method from the class User, create a new User.

```
import User from "./user.model";
jest.mock('./user.model');

describe('Testing user class', () => {


    it("Should return a user object if a record will be found", async () => {
        const mockGetUser = jest.spyOn(User, 'getUser');
        const mockedUser = new User('Testing value', 'testing', 'testing@example.com');
    
        mockGetUser.mockResolvedValue(mockedUser);
        console.log(mockedUser);
    
        const result = await User.getUser('testing@example.com', 'testing');
    
        // Assert that the result is the same as the mocked user object
        expect(result).toEqual(mockedUser);

    
        // Restore the mock after the test
        mockGetUser.mockRestore();
    });
    
});
```

The result and the mocked user are empty objects in an array...
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does not work? Is the test failing? If so, with what error message? And what does `jest.mock('./user.model');` do?

Comment: "*What I am doing wrong?*" - you are not testing the implementation of your class method. You're overwriting `User.getUser` with a mock/spy, and then are calling that directly. What's the point? What kind of mistakes did you expect this test to catch?

Comment: I dont get any error messages. my test passes. But after logging and expecting other values (like an empty array of obj), my tests still passed.... 
I logged in the mocking values and the results and are [{}]...

Comment: "you are not testing the implementation of your class method. You're overwriting User.getUser with a mock/spy, and then are calling that directly. " 
Can you help me with this please? I just need a model to be done by my code and get inspired by it...

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your test always passed is that you mock the result to always be equal to the data you provided:

```
const mockGetUser = jest.spyOn(User, 'getUser');
const mockedUser = new User('Testing value', 'testing', 'testing@example.com');
mockGetUser.mockResolvedValue(mockedUser);
```

Then you test against the same value:

```
const result = await User.getUser('testing@example.com', 'testing');
// Assert that the result is the same as the mocked user object
expect(result).toEqual(mockedUser);
```

It means that whenever it executes `getUser`, the result value will always be `mockedUser`, which is the same as the `result`.

If you want to test your class correctly, you can either mock the user records or the `readSmallRecord` method instead of the `getUser`.

Here is an example of using `readSmallRecord` mock:

Assuming:

1. the method is stored in a file called `./user.method`
2. the `User` class has the following constructor or similar (because you didn't provide the complete code):

```
constructor(name: string, passwordPlain: string, email: string) {
       this.name = name
       this.email = email
       this.passwordPlain = passwordPlain
}
```

This line helps you to set up the users record, so that you can test whether a certain user exists in the record.

```
let mockRecordValue = ''
jest.mock('./user.method', () => ({
    readSmallRecord: () => mockRecordValue,
}))
```

You can then add the test suites as follow:

```
describe('Testing user class', () => {
    it("Should return a user object if a record will be found", async () => {
        mockRecordValue = '[{ "email": "testing@example.com", "name": "Testing value", "passwordPlain": "testing" }]'
        const mockedUser = new User('Testing value', 'testing', 'testing@example.com');
        let result = await User.getUser('testing@example.com', 'testing');
    
        // Assert that the result is the same as the mocked user object
        expect(result).toEqual(mockedUser);

        mockRecordValue = '[{ "email": "otheruser@example.com", "name": "Testing value", "passwordPlain": "testing" }]'
        result = await User.getUser('testing@example.com', 'testing');
        
        // Assert that the result throws error on user not found
        expect(result).toEqual(Error('User not found'))

        mockRecordValue = 'invalidJSON'
        result = await User.getUser('testing@example.com', 'testing');

        // Assert that the result throws error on fetching user data 
        expect(result).toEqual(Error('Failed to fetch user data'))
    });
    
});
```